# how can I use a function as an argument to another function,

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a simple code that displays 3 sets of greetings in accordance to what day of the week a user inputs. I am learning about functions as I am a beginner so please answer in terms of a function usage.

I tried to set a function for the greeting instructions and another as an input from the user which is passed as an argument to the first function. please tell me what's wrong with the code.

```
def action(user_response):
  
  greeting = "hello madam"
  greeting2 = " Good afternoon madam"
  greeting3 = "Have a good weekend"

  while user_response == "tuesday" or "monday":
   return greeting 
   if user_response == "wednesday" or "thursday": 
     return greeting2

  return greeting3
     



def user_response():
  user_input = input("what day of the week is it: ").lower() 
  print(f"{user_input}")
  return user_response()

def main():
  action(user_response)
  user_response()

main()
```

Comment: There are many things wrong. What symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: oh, the output basically is a loop asking the user for an input of the day and repeat

Comment: You should put () on your user_response() under main.

Comment: Note `user_response == "tuesday" or "monday"` doesn't do what you probably think: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/3001761

Comment: A loop? You have `while user_response == "tuesday" or "monday":`. This will always be True because it's seen as `while (user_response == "tuesday") or "monday":` and "monday" is a non-empty string and treated as true. The first line in the while loop is a `return` so you leave the loop. No real looping here.

Comment: @quamrana I disagree with the duplicate close reason. He has many different issues apart from that.

Comment: @bharel:I said as much in the first comment. Also the close reason is the first item discussed in the accepted answer. Still, feel free to vote for reopen.

Comment: @quamrana If I vote it'll automatically reopen. Either way, like you said, if there are multiple issues I'm not sure the duplicate is a correct target, unless we add duplicates to all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code, lets go step by step:

- The condition `user_response == "tuesday" or "monday"` will return `True`
  because: if user_response is not equal to tuesday (which isn't, because you're comparing a function with a string), you will get "monday" because of `or` condition, `False or something -> something`. So you get `if "monday"`, that evaluates to `True`, because not-empty string evaluates to `True` in python.
- If you want to pass a function as argument, you need to call that function inside the called function. You're not returning any value from `user_response`, so you're retrieving `None` (but you aren't, because you're not capturing the result). You should return user_input from `user_response`
- If you `return` a value, you have to capture and print it, otherwise, the function would exit doing nothing. I've modified your code so `action` print the greeting, only exiting at the weekend after printing.

The execution order would be:

- Call `action` passing `user_response` as argument
- Call `user_response` inside `action` and retrieve the value
- Return a greeting based on the value retrieved from `user_response`

```py
def action(user_func):
    greeting = "hello madam"
    greeting2 = "Good afternoon madam"
    greeting3 = "Have a good weekend"
    user_answer = user_func()
    while user_answer not in ('friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'):
        if user_answer in ("monday", "tuesday"):
            print(greeting)
        else:
            print(greeting2)
        user_answer = user_func()
    print(greeting3)
    return

def user_response():
  user_input = input("what day of the week is it: ").lower()
  return user_input

def main():
  action(user_response)

main()
```

Comment: Hello, thankyou so much for taking the time to answer. Just a question, I notice that instead of user_response you have added user_func as an arguement, why is that?

Comment: Nothing special, just wanted to highlight the fact that is a function, and that it wasn't scope-shadowed from original user_response function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: so when I use the code, I chage that to user_response right? otherwise the function would be nothing since it is not defined.

Comment: You misunderstood. user_func is declared as argument to action, every function passed to action will be named user_func. If you use user_response in action code and then you pass another function, that would execute user_response, indepently of the function you passed to action. However, user_func will be always the function you used as argument when calling action

Answer (score 0):

You would want your functions to return a string, which you could pass through as a parameter in to another function. Or pass a reference to the function for this to be called within the destination

**For example, something like this for passing through the response**

```
def action(response):
print(response)

def user_response():
  user_input = input("what day of the week is it: ").lower() 
  return user_input

def main():    
  response = user_response()
  action(response)

main()
```

**Or Something like this passing through a reference to the function**

```
def action(fn):
    response = fn()
    print(response)
    
def user_response():
  user_input = input("what day of the week is it: ").lower() 
  return user_input

def main():    
  action(user_response)

main()
```

Comment: well this didn't work for me sorry

Comment: @dinonuggie I've updated the examples to work fully on their own - I didn't define "action" as a function last time to give a quick example of what i meant, but i've included everything you need to test now, you can confirm this by running the code on its own somewhere